# Specific English term for the type of work is flexible and one position can be held by two people

Tags: single-word-requests

I need help to find the term for this definition:

"The type of work is flexible and one position can be held by two people".

Would you kindly help me with this term?

Comment: Where I work the announcements for such roles say "suitable for job-sharing".

Comment: I suppose you could say that such a role is 'shareable'.

Answer (score 5):

One type of such a position is described by *Jobshare*

= “a situation where the duties and the pay of one job are divided between two people who work at different times during the day or week”

[Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jobshare)

Some flexibility (of timetabling, duties and responsibilities) is often implicit in such a shared position.